# Gitlab auto deploy job fails with i/o timeout to cluster api endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab-ci-runner, google-kubernetes-engine

automatic deploy of my gitlab hello-world app fails with a timeout. It seems it cannot connect to cluster api endpoint. [Full console output is available here](https://gitlab.com/Cardamone/minimal-ruby-app/-/jobs/47468130)

```
Using KUBE_CA_PEM...
Cluster "gitlab-deploy" set.
User "gitlab-deploy" set.
Context "gitlab-deploy" created.
Switched to context "gitlab-deploy".

Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:80: i/o timeout
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Any idea?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please run `gcloud config list` to ensure you are using the correct cluster.

Use the following commands shown below to ensure that you set the correct context before deploying your application. You can find further information in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/clusters/operations#setting_the_default_cluster) link.

$ gcloud config set container/cluster `<your-cluster-name>`
$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials `<your-cluster-name>`
$ gcloud config set compute/zone `<cluster-zone>`
$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials
$ gcloud auth application-default login

If above commands give you errors please post the output to help troubleshoot further. Ensure you don't include any security sensitive information.

I would also like to ask you to provide the steps/commands you are using  to create the deployment. The console link that you provide is not available.